# Display a UI element (Image, Text) in Data Template of a List View on click of List View Item

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

The Data Template Code

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="CachelvTemplate">
            <Grid Margin="21,3,21,3" Height="60">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black"  FontSize="20"/>
                <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="/Assets/Icons/selectedCache.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Fill" MaxHeight="20" MaxWidth="20" Opacity="0" />
            </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
```

List View Code

```
 <ListView x:Name="cacheList" Tapped="cacheList_ItemClick"                     
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CachelvTemplate}" />
```

Now on click of a list item, I would like to either change the opacity of the image (from Data Template) to become one, or somehow make it visible. Only for the selected List View Item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all You should have used ItemClick or SelectionChanged event instead of Tapped. I ll use `SelectionChanged`  event. You can use of `VisualTreeHelper` to get the image control of selected item

```
private void cacheList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
            {
                ListViewItem selectedItem = (sender as ListView).ContainerFromItem(item) as ListViewItem;
                Image image = FindElementInVisualTree<Image>(selectedItem);
                if(image!=null)
                {
                    image.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
        }
        private T FindElementInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject parentElement) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);
            if (count == 0) return null;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                    return (T)child;
                else
                {
                    var result = FindElementInVisualTree<T>(child);
                    if (result != null)
                        return result;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

**Update to make unselected item image collapsed**

```
 private void cacheList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
        {
            ListViewItem selectedItem = (sender as ListView).ContainerFromItem(item) as ListViewItem;
            Image image = FindElementInVisualTree<Image>(selectedItem);
            if (image != null)
            {
                image.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            FindListViewItem((sender as ListView), selectedItem);
        }
    }
    private void FindListViewItem(DependencyObject parent,ListViewItem selectedItem)
    {
        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (child is ListViewItem && (child as ListViewItem) != selectedItem)
            {
                Image unselectedimage = FindElementInVisualTree<Image>(child);
                if (unselectedimage != null)
                {
                    unselectedimage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
            else
            {
              FindListViewItem(child, selectedItem);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes this works like a charm, but my entire use case isn't complete. When i select a different list item, i would like the image from un-selected list items to be not visible. Any idea ?

Comment: I have a list view. 

The selected list item is highlighted (background colour is changed) and a tick mark is shown. 

The tick mark is an image that needs to be shown only for the selected item list view. 

Now, what happens is, once selected that tick mark continues to be visible even when not selected. I hence need the tick mark to be visible only for the selected list item. 

Please see the images attached in the link for details

[link] https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4JsxIX3-8pNRXZJckN5dVRSQTg

Comment: Yes I understood the problem. Are you using MVVM concept?If so please post the code

Comment: If you are using MVVM. Have one more property lets say IsSelected. Bind it to Image control Visibility. On selection changed make selected item.IsSelected to Visible and other items IsSelected to Collapsed

Comment: Yes, I am using an MVVM Concept. The list view is a user control which is being used in a Flyout for the Metro App and in a page for the phone App. (Developing a universal Application)

Comment: could your provide any lookup material for the same. I am not to certain how to go about it

Comment: No, when i use the code you suggested the count is always 1, no matter how many elements i have.

Comment: But since i have understood what you tried to suggest in the code i've tried to do this

Comment: Check the updated one. Let me know whether it works.

Comment: What you tried to is also correct. But there is one mistake in that. Since selecteditem is ListViewItem that you are comparing with your data object. That is wrong. It should be  if(cacheitem == selecteditem.DataContext)

Comment: But it threw exceptions in the Visual State Manager Method. It said that the element passed was a mismatched element passed.

Comment: Your Solution works like a charm! Thank you so much! Have been stuck on this for far too long.

Comment: Yes cacheItem is not ListViewItem. It is dataobject that is bound to listviewitem. You cant pass it VisualTreeHelper