# Pass value UserControl to ViewModel of View Page

Tags: c#, mvvm, user-controls, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Here is the complete [**Sample code**](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=72A2505C9C6FA57C!5349&authkey=!AOhd3T7hcGORAYE&ithint=file%2crar)
Using **MVVM** pattern My requirement is to have a ListView where

1. *If user Taps inside ListView on checkBox **Storyboard Animation** should play for `True` `False` and the ListView binded value should be updated in database. For true the tick should pop up with animation for false the tick should become invisible with animation.* 
   **Solved** as per @Elvis Xia answer

   ---
2. If user taps on ListviewItem Navigate to new page with value
3. [Blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF93t.png)

Now I went with Usercontrol creation for the datatemplate. Here I want to identify both events separately user clicking on `checkbox` or clicking on `Item` separately.
 Using `ICommand` I am creating two Delegates that gets binded to two transparent button which relays tapped event.
 Dependency of creating transparent buttons and creating delgates while binding them made me think surely there must a better way in which I can utilize **MVVM** for these events without any *code behind*.

**UserControl XAML**

```
<Button Background="LightBlue" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="4" Command="{x:Bind sampleItem.itemTapped}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">

    <Grid Margin="20">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind sampleItem.sampleText}" FontSize="30"/>
        <Image Grid.Column="1" Height="60" Width="60" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/check_off.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <Image x:Name="image" Grid.Column="1" Height="60" Width="60" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/check_on.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Visibility="Collapsed" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Button x:Name="btnFav" Grid.Column="1"  Height="60" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Transparent" Command="{x:Bind sampleItem.favTapped}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <!--<Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding favTapped}" />
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>-->
                <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding isFav}" Value="true">
                    <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryboardCheckOn}"/>
                </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
                <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding isFav}" Value="false">
                    <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryboardCheckOff}"/>
                </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

**UserControl XAML codeBehind**

```
MainPageModel sampleItem { get { return this.DataContext as MainPageModel; } }
        public MainPageUserControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContextChanged += (s, e) => this.Bindings.Update();
        }
```

**Viewmodel Code**

```
public async Task GetData()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (i == 3)
            sampleList.Add(new MainPageModel { sampleText = "Selected", isFav = true, favTapped= new DelegateCommand<MainPageModel>(this.OnFavTapped), itemTapped= new DelegateCommand<MainPageModel>(this.OnItemTapped)});
        else
            sampleList.Add(new MainPageModel { sampleText = "UnSelected"+i.ToString(), isFav = null, favTapped = new DelegateCommand<MainPageModel>(this.OnFavTapped), itemTapped = new DelegateCommand<MainPageModel>(this.OnItemTapped) });
}
}
private void OnFavTapped(MainPageModel arg)
{
    if (arg.isFav == null) arg.isFav = true;
    else
        arg.isFav = !arg.isFav;
}
private void OnItemTapped(MainPageModel arg)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Button Value: "+arg.sampleText);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Selected Item Value: "+selectedItem.sampleText);
}
```

**MainPage Xaml**

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.sampleList}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectedItem="{Binding ViewModel.selectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>                       
                            <userControls:MainPageUserControl/>                       
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
```

There must be a better way to achieve the desired result using code behind.

Comment: Its good approach if  you do it in ViewModel. And yeah you have to implement command. If you use PRISM it already has it implemented.

Comment: Your using DataTriggerBehaviour right to play the storyboard. I don't understand why you have to access it in viewmodel.

Comment: And I didn't understand second part of your question. Can you elaborate it?

Comment: If you want to make item as selected when you click one button-> have property in viewmodel. Bind it to SelecredItem of ListView with TwoWay binding. When you click on the button, take the DataContext of button and assign it to SelecredItem property of viewmodel

Comment: You don't have to remove UserControl. Using that you can Bind it to Viewmodel. if you have problems with that let me know. Right now I'm not in front of PC. So I can't see your sample. But I had a look  at it earlier

Comment: Please  have a look at it. This is similar to your  requirement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36541490/display-a-ui-element-image-text-in-data-template-of-a-list-view-on-click-of-l/36541757#36541757

Comment: OK. You need one property in Viewmodel. Probably in model class which you are binding to ListView ItemSource. Bind it to image Visibility property. When you thinkap on the button you can get the item Using DataContext. Then make that property Visibility to Visible. Hope you are understanding.. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109058/discussion-between-jerin-and-archana).

Comment: Sorry I can't access chat link

Comment: Yesterday even I wasnt able to today I can. Pls check again.

Comment: is there any problem moving favTapped and itemTapped  from MainPageModel to Viewmodel. And i'm not able to access source code

Comment: No there is no problem if its possible as long as I clicking on favTapped wont trigger itemTapped and vice versa and it gets called for each item.

Comment: I dint get you. You are telling if you move the code events are not triggering?

Comment: Check my answer. I hope your usercontrol DataContext is MainPageViewModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ViewMOdel()
{ 
       public ViewModel()
    {
favTapped= new DelegateCommand<MainPageModel>(this.OnFavTapped)
 itemTapped= new DelegateCommand<MainPageModel>(this.OnItemTapped)
    }

public async Task GetData()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (i == 3)
                sampleList.Add(new MainPageModel { sampleText = "Selected", isFav = true});
            else
                sampleList.Add(new MainPageModel { sampleText = "UnSelected"+i.ToString(), isFav = null});
    }
    }
    private void OnFavTapped(MainPageModel arg)
    {
        if (arg.isFav == null) arg.isFav = true;
        else
            arg.isFav = !arg.isFav;
    }
    private void OnItemTapped(MainPageModel arg)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Button Value: "+arg.sampleText);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Selected Item Value: "+selectedItem.sampleText);
    }
    }
```

Binding should be like this

```
<Button x:Name="btnFav" Grid.Column="1"  Height="60" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Transparent" Command="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=Tag.favTapped}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

**Update**

```
<ListView  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.sampleList}"  x:Name="Listview"IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectedItem="{Binding ViewModel.selectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>                       
                                <userControls:MainPageUserControl Tag="{Binding DataContext,ElementName=Listview}"/>                       
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
 <Button x:Name="btnFav" Grid.Column="1"  Height="60" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Transparent" Command="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=Tag.favTapped}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

**Update2 using EventTriggerBehavior**

```
 favTapped = new DelegateCommand<RoutedEventArgs>(this.OnFavTapped);

private void OnFavTapped(RoutedEventArgs arg)
        {
         var item =  (( arg.OriginalSource )as Button).DataContext as MainPageModel
        }

<Button n x:Name="btnFav" Grid.Column="1"  Height="60" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Transparent"   >
            <interact:Interaction.Behaviors>

                <interactcore:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click" >
                    <interactcore:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=usercontrol, Path=Tag.favTapped}" />
                </interactcore:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Button>
```

Comment: My userControl `Datacontext` is  MainPageModel as can be seen from 'code behind'. If I set datacontext as MainPageViewModel then how will I bind. My hierarchy is Listview(with observable collection bind)--> Itemtemplate is Usercontrol(which takes binding as MainPageModel). Your solution is the first thing I tried but the problem was where to define the command.

Comment: Ok. Im not sure try this. Give ListViewname as  elementname  instead of usercontrolname

Comment: Yes. I said inside Usercontrol. Use {Binding ElementName=ListviewName,Path=DataContext.favTapped}.

Comment: Check the update. I have used Tag property. I tested also. It works

Comment: Yes it worked. This would require specifying names to listview and usercontrol. So which method should I use my earlier method with {x:Bind} or this method. Compile time binding has been introduced recently but there should be a way to implement it also right

Comment: This way is better than what you were doing before. Before you were declaring event handler in model. That is not recommended. You should always do in ViewModel.

Comment: One more thing You said its not possible to get access to model data if you use Behaviours. It is possible. I ll update the answer for that

Comment: Thnx for the update will do some research on tags now.

Answer (score 1):

The DataContext of every item in your project is an instance of `MainPageModel` class. So the favTapped command should be added to `MainPageModel` class. And it is a command, so favTapped should be an instance of a new class,which implements `ICommand` interface.

And if you don't want the animation to show at the page's first load, you can set `isFav` to `bool?`. And when the page first loads, set the value of isFav to null, thus it won't trigger the animation action.

Below are the Codes snippets and Demo Link:

ViewModelCommands.cs:

```
public class ViewModelCommands : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        //if it's a tapped event
        if (parameter is TappedRoutedEventArgs)
        {
            var tappedEvent = (TappedRoutedEventArgs)parameter;
            var gridSource = (Grid)tappedEvent.OriginalSource;
            var dataContext = (MainPageModel)gridSource.DataContext;
            //if tick is true then set to false, or the opposite.
            if (dataContext.isFav == null)
            {
                dataContext.isFav = true;
            } else
            {
                dataContext.isFav = !dataContext.isFav;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainPageModel.cs:

```
 public class MainPageModel:BindableBase
{

    public MainPageModel() {
        favTapped = new ViewModelCommands();
    }
    public ViewModelCommands favTapped { get; set; }
    private string _sampleText;
    public string sampleText
    {
        get
        {
            return this._sampleText;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _sampleText, value);
        }
    }
    private bool? _isFav;
    public bool? isFav
    {
        get
        {
            return this._isFav;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _isFav, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the complete Demo:[Demo Project](https://github.com/elvisxia/StackOverFlowDemos/tree/master/UWP(CS)%20Demos/PassValuesUcToVm)

**Update:**

When using `DelegateCommand`, you can add the command Property to MainPageModel.cs and since the DataContext of the items are MainPageModel instances. You can use `this.isFav` to change the clicked item's value of `isFav`.

Here are the codes of MainPageModel.cs:

```
public class MainPageModel : BindableBase
{
    private DelegateCommand _favTapped;

    public DelegateCommand favTapped
    {
        get
        {
            if (_favTapped == null)
            {
                _favTapped = new DelegateCommand(() =>
                {
                    //Here implements the check on or off logic
                    this.CheckOnOff();
                }, () => true);
            }
            return _favTapped;
        }
        set { _favTapped = value; }
    }

    private void CheckOnOff()
    {
        if (this.isFav == null)
        {
            this.isFav = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.isFav = !this.isFav;
        }
    }
    private string _sampleText;
    public string sampleText
    {
        get
        {
            return this._sampleText;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _sampleText, value);
        }
    }
    private bool? _isFav;
    public bool? isFav
    {
        get
        {
            return this._isFav;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _isFav, value);
        }
    }
}
```

> For Listview item selected

You can use ListView.ItemClick Event. But you should also set IsItemClickEnabled="True",otherwise the event handler won't be fired.

> For The subitem of Listview tapped

You can use Tapped Event of userControl.

Here are the Xaml codes, that shows how to register the above two events:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <ListView IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick_1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.sampleList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <userControls:MainPageUserControl  Tapped="MainPageUserControl_Tapped"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Here how would you suggest I will be able to differentiate between the three event clicks of 1) Listview item selected 2) The subitem of Listview tapped 3) SelectedItem. Also template 10 already has a predefined ICommand which I am utilizing as `DelegateCommand<MainPageModel>(this.OnFavTapped)` If you can have a look at the chat discussion in comments above you will find the workaround that I reached. Could you suggest a better method to identify the three events

Comment: What do you mean by ListView itemselected and selecteditem?  There is selectionchanged event that you can use for getting Selecteditem or you can use item click event of ListView

Comment: @Jerin I've updated the answer. Hope it be helpful to you. Currently I am not able to upload my project. I can upload later if you want.

Comment: I dont want to use a code behind but using MVVM just my viewmodel. Is there any better method in which I can do it other than my current sample.
@Archana I have update the question with latest build. Is there a better way.